# cx_Oracle-like package for Clojure

Tags: python, oracle, jdbc, clojure

I'm coming from a very heavy Python->Oracle development environment and have been playing around with Clojure quite a bit.  I love the ease of access that cx_Oracle gives me to the database on the Python end and was wondering if Clojure has something similar.

Specifically what I'm looking for is something to give me easy access to a database connection, ala cx_Oracle's "username/password@tns_name" format.

The best I've come up with so far is:

```clj
(defn get-datasource [user password server service]
    {:datasource (clj-dbcp.core/make-datasource {:adapter :oracle
                                               :style :service-name
                                               :host server
                                               :service-name service
                                               :user user
                                               :password password})})
```

This requires the server however and 95% of my users don't have the knowledge of what server they're hitting, just the tns name from tnsnames.ora.

In addition, I don't understand when I have a database connection and when it disconnects.  With cx_Oracle I either had to do a `with cx_Oracle.connect()...` or a `connection.close()` to close the connection.

Can someone give me guidance as to how datasources work as far as connections go and the easiest way to connect to a database given a username, password, and tns alias?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best use Clojure's most idiomatic database library [clojure.java.jdbc](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc).

First, because the Oracle driver isn't available from a maven repository, we need to download the latest one and install it in our local repository, using the [lein-localrepo](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo) plugin:

```
lein localrepo install -r D:\Path\To\Repo\
                          D:\Path\To\ojdbc6.jar
                          oracle.jdbc/oracledriver "12.1.0.1"
```

Now we can reference it in our project.clj, together with clojure.java.jdbc.

```
(defproject oracle-connect "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.3"]
                 [oracle.jdbc/oracledriver "12.1.0.1"]])
```

After starting a REPL we can connect to the database through a default host/port/SID connection

```
(ns oracle-connect
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]))

(def db
  {:classname    "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   :subprotocol  "oracle:thin"
   :subname      "//@hostname:port:sid"
   :user         "username"
   :password     "password"}))

(jdbc/query db ["select ? as one from dual" 1])
```

`db` is just a basic map, referred to as the db-spec. It is not a real connection, but has all the information needed to make one. Clojure.java.jdbc makes one when needed, for instance in `(query db ..)`.

We need to enter the classname manually because clojure.java.jdbc doesn't have a default mapping between the subprotocol and the classname for Oracle. This is probably because the Oracle JDBC driver has both thin and OCI JDBC connection options.

To make a connection with a TNS named database, the driver needs the location of the tnsnames.ora file. This is done by setting a system property called `oracle.net.tns_admin`.

```
(System/setProperty "oracle.net.tns_admin"
                    "D:/oracle/product/12.1.0.1/db_1/NETWORK/ADMIN")
```

Once this is set all we need for subname is the tnsname of the database.

```
(def db
  {:classname    "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   :subprotocol  "oracle:thin"
   :subname      "@tnsname"
   :user         "username"
   :password     "password"}))

(jdbc/query db ["select ? as one from dual" 1])
```

Now on to the *'how do connections work'* part. As stated earlier, clojure.java.jdbc creates connections when needed, for instance within the query function.

If all you want to do is transform the results of a query, you can give in two extra optional named parameters: `:row-fn` and `:result-set-fn`. Every row is transformed with the row-fn, after which the whole resultset is transformed with the result-set-fn.

Both of these are executed within the context of the connection, so the connection is guaranteed to be open until all these actions have been performed, *unless these functions return lazy sequences*.

By default the :result-set-fn is defined as a `doall` guaranteeing all results are realized, but if you redefine it be sure to realize all lazy results. Usually whenever you get a connection or resultset closed exception while using results outside of the scope the problem is you didn't.

The connection only exists within the scope of the `query` function. At the end it is closed. This means that every query results in a connection. If you want multiple queries done within one connection, you can wrap them in a `with-db-connection`:

```
(jdbc/with-db-connection [c db]
  (doall (map #(jdbc/query c ["select * from EMP where DEPTNO = ?" %])
               (jdbc/query c ["select * from DEPT"] :row-fn :DEPTNO))))
```

In the `with-db-connection` binding you bind the db-spec to a var, and use that var instead of the db-spec in statements inside the binding scope. It creates a connection and adds that to the var. The other statements will use that connection. This is especially handy when creating dynamic queries based on the result of other queries.

The same thing goes for `with-db-transaction`. It has the same semantics as `with-db-connection`, however here the scope not only guarantees the same connection is used, but also that either all statements or none succeed by wrapping them in a transaction block. Both `with-db-connection` and `with-db-transaction` are nestable.

There are also more advanced options like creating connection pools and instead of having `query` et al. create or reuse single connections, have them draw a connection from the pool. See the [clojure-doc.org documentation](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/home.html) for those.

Comment: WOW, I have to say that this is one of the best and most detailed answers I've ever read on stackoverflow.  That being said, it's going to take me some time to digest it and test it, then I'll accept it as the answer.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: So, I'm unable to connect.  With :subname "@tnsalias" I'm getting the error:

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified

If I use :subname "tnsalias" I get the error:

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

I'm able to tnsping the db with the tnsalias so I know that the issue is on the clojure/java/etc end.

Comment: All of the protocols are TCP

Comment: The problem was the location property isn't a connection property, but a system property. The examples are fixed and doublechecked now. It worked here because I had previously set it as java property in the project.clj but had forgotten to remove it. Sorry for the trouble !

Comment: <deleted comment... not valid to discussion>